# Where is Chap. 9 in Baby Rudin taught?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, online-resources

I'm (once again after February 2015) reading through Chap. 9 of the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition. This chapter is on differentiation and integration of functions of several variables.

In the MIT Analysis I courses archived under the MIT OCW initiative, Baby Rudin has been covered only as far as Chap. 8.

Are there any similar course archives available online featuring also notes, homework assignments (with solutions), and exams (with solutions) covering Chap. 9 of Baby Rudin?

Comment: I do not think there is any online supplement to chapter 9 of Rudin’s book, but my suggestion is that instead you read Pugh’s real mathematical analysis book for learning multivariable analysis

Comment: @Selflearner would it be practical for me to just pick up that book and start reading it from the chapter on multivariable analysis? You see, I've read through almost all of the first seven chapters of Baby Rudin, and have done most of the problems as far as Chap. 6!

Comment: Yes, if you have read til chapter 6 of Rudin’s book, you will not face any major problem reading right the chapter on multivariable analysis in Pugh’s book. But some notions might be new to you, whose definitions you can check in the earlier chapters, but this will not often happen except in one case or two